# removing ubuntu from a laptop (corrupted ubuntu)

Tags: dual-boot

I wanted to update my (very old) Ubuntu installation on my dual boot laptop. The other OS is win7. However, when I tried to boot into it I got: \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr cannot be loaded. Status 0xE0000000C. I assume the mbr is the master boot record for the Ubuntu installation.

I looked at my C: drive and there's a WUBILDR and WUBILDR.MBR file there. Is it as simple as deleting them? ALSO, I just noticed there is no UBUNTU partition. If I delete these files and then get rid of the startup option for Ubuntu, is that all I have to do?

(My goal is to have an up-to-date Ubuntu OS alongside Win 7).

Comment: It looks like you had installed Ubuntu from inside Windows using WUBI.EXE. This method does not create a partition, but uses a large file inside the Windows partition as a virtual partition. To remove Ubuntu installed this way you have to use the Windows Uninstall process inside Windows. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wubi_(Ubuntu_installer)

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the first thing I would suggest to do is uninstall Ubuntu via the Windows side, perhaps using Your Uninstaller Pro! or Revo to ensure all files are successfully wiped. Any uninstall methods that clean leftover files and registry.

Now you could use [WUBI](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer) to install, however this does not make a partition. I would recommend getting the latest [Ubuntu iso file](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest), and installing from CD. The new install method also has an improved method of showing the room on the hard drive and how much room Ubuntu will use. Thumbs up if I helped, thanks!